# Interceptor making two calls in API

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I'm working on a project and everything is working well... and when I request something to the API (like the example below) it only sends, obviously, a single request:

```
this.httpClient.get<MyInterface>('my_api').subscribe(data => this.items = data);
```

But I wanted to take advantage of Interceptors in the new HttpClient, so I started to search examples and I found [**this**](http://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Jul/15/angular-http-client.html).

I've defined everything as in the post:

*progress-interceptor.ts*:

```
@Injectable()
export class ProgressInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  progress$: Observable<number | null>;
  private progressSubject: Subject<number | null>;

  constructor() {
    this.progressSubject = new ReplaySubject<number | null>(1);
    this.progress$ = this.progressSubject.asObservable();
  }

  intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
    const reportingRequest = req.clone({ reportProgress: true });
    const handle = next.handle(reportingRequest);

    handle.subscribe((event: HttpEvent<T>) => {
      switch (event.type) {
        case HttpEventType.Sent:
          this.progressSubject.next(undefined);
          break;

        case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
        case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
          if (event.total) {
            this.progressSubject.next(Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100));
          }
          break;

        case HttpEventType.Response:
          this.progressSubject.next(100);
          break;

        default:
        break;
      }
    });

    return handle;
  }
}
```

*progress-component.ts*:

```
export class ProgressComponent implements OnInit {

  progressPercentage$: Observable<number>;

  @Input() color: ProgressBarColor = 'primary';

  @ViewChild(MdProgressBar) private progressBar: MdProgressBar;

  constructor(private interceptor: ProgressInterceptor) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.progressPercentage$ = this.interceptor.progress$
        .map(progress => {
          if (isNil(progress)) {
            this.setMode('indeterminate');

            return 0;
          } else {
            this.setMode('determinate');

            return progress;
          }
        });
  }

  private setMode(mode: ProgressBarMode) {
    this.progressBar.mode = mode;
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*:

```
const interceptor = new ProgressInterceptor();

@NgModule({
  // ...
  providers: [
    { provide: ProgressInterceptor, useValue: interceptor },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useValue: interceptor, multi: true }
  ]
})
```

The problem is: now, with this interceptor, when I do any request, it hits the API twice. Why? I suspect that's because the `subscribe` inside the `intercept()` of `ProgressInterceptor`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Note that somebody commented on the article pointing this issue out, so I've updated it with the suggested correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your guess is correct, by subscribing to the handle within the interceptor, you are triggering the observable chain again and therefore trigger the API call again.

In your case the appropriate operator is `.do(...)` ([see the docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-do)) as you only want to observe what is happening inside of the chain but have no intention to manipulate anything within it.

It should look something like this:

```
intercept<T>(req: HttpRequest<T>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<T>> {
  const reportingRequest = req.clone({ reportProgress: true });
  return next.handle(reportingRequest)
             .do((event: HttpEvent<T>) => {
                switch (event.type) {
                  case HttpEventType.Sent:
                    this.progressSubject.next(undefined);
                    break;

                  case HttpEventType.DownloadProgress:
                  case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
                    if (event.total) {
                      this.progressSubject.next(Math.round((event.loaded / event.total) * 100));
                    }
                    break;

                  case HttpEventType.Response:
                    this.progressSubject.next(100);
                    break;

                  default:
                  break;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Can you please help me with more one thing? Actually I'm receiving the following error *"ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'ProgressInterceptor'..."*. Do you know how to solve it? I guess it's giving this error because this line `const interceptor = new ProgressInterceptor();`, but I don't know how to remove this and make it work... if I remove it and put it in `useClass` directly I get `No provider for ProgressInterceptor`. Thanks.

Comment: You either write `providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useValue: ProgressInterceptor, multi: true }]` or `providers: [ProgressInterceptor, { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useExisting: ProgressInterceptor, multi: true }]`. Do not call new on the interceptor. Angular will instantiate it for you.